# Adding Tag to the type declaration

Tags: c, rational-number, rhapsody

I need to add a tag value in the Type declaration as shown here:

[image]

The problem is that I keep getting the Tag name instead of the Tag value in the generated code. as follows.

[image]

### any clues?

My original need was to make some #define lines and I was trying to make a stereotype for this

Comment: #define does not define a new type. The question is not clear for me. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: from C point of view you are totally correct. but this is the only way I can think of making #define in Rhapsody (work around). I just want to make some pre-build configurations in Rhapsody and don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the tag value is not evaluated in the declaration field. Here is a workaround:

Let's say the name of the tag is "**repeat_time**":

[image]

Do not use the tag in the declaration field:

[image]

Instead, add it to the `CPP_CG::Type::SpecificationEpilog` property,
(note the space before the tag name):

[image]

Note 1:
Consider using a variable instead of a type, see the following picture for details:

[image]

Generated code:

```
//#[ type CANSM_MODEREQ_REPEAT_TIME
#define CANSM_MODEREQ_REPEAT_TIME 100
//#]

//## attribute CANSM_MODERSP_REPEAT_TIME
#define CANSM_MODERSP_REPEAT_TIME 200
```

Note 2: Consider using a stereotype to overload the properties.